# Should a NSFetchedResultsController always be used with Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I'm creating a simple notes app, and I just recently learned the basics of Core Data(and i'm a beginner in general).

Now, in the tutorial [I learned the basics](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-to-core-data/) of Core Data they did not use `NSFetchedResultsController` at all, and I'm also learning Core Data with [Apple sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html) and they use it there.

And I'm wondering if should I dig into this and learn how to use `NSFetchedResultsController` or is it too advanced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do really!

If you want to display a list of objects of the same entity with a filter or order then yes its great for that.
If you want to have a form where attribute values of an entity object are change then no!

From the name of the class, its used for a list of fetched results, so if you're only dealing with one object (i.e. the above form case) then its not very useful.
The main benefit of using it in a `UITableView` or `UICollectionView` is that you get notififed when objects are changed, inserted or deleted that match the predicate of the `NSFetchRequest`.

Comment: I have an entity called Note with an attribute called content...and I only want to save and fetch the content and display it on a table view, so I shouldn't use NSFetchedResultsController right? @Rich

Comment: @user3412425 you probably want a `NSFetchedResultsController` to display the list of notes, but when selecting a `Note` alter that object directly with the attribute accessor methods :)